# Relation between the inequalities $x |y| >y^2$, $x>y$, and $y>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Is $x |y| > y^2$?

(1) $x > y$
(2) $y > 0$

Determine if:

A) statement 1 is sufficient to answer the question stem but not statement 2
B) statement 2 is sufficient to answer the question stem but not statement 1
C) if both statements combined are sufficient but not independently
D) if both statements separately are sufficient to answer
E) neither statement is sufficient, not combined are they sufficient.

This is a GMAT question.

#### Progress

Since |y| is positive... can we divide by |y|? I don't think we can since if y is negative, the right side becomes -y right?

Can we simplify the base equation any further?

When y is positive, Is x>y?

When y is negative, Is X<-y?

1) insufficient because 
Suppose that y=-3 and x=2, then answer is no.
Suppose that y=1 and x=2, then answer is yes.
2) insufficient since we do not know the value of x. We do not know if X>Y

However if you take the statements together, then you know that X>Y. sufficient.

We can also do this problem by taking values and checking right?

Is x·|y| > y^2? 
(1) x > y
(2) y > 0

1) Suppose x=3 and y=2 --> 6>4--> yes

Suppose x=3 and y=-2 --> 6>4 --> yes

Suppose x=-2 and y=-3 --> -6>9 --> no

insufficient.

2) Suppose x=2 and y=3 --> 6>9 --> no

Suppose x=5 and y=3 -->15>9 --> yes

insufficient

c) suppose x= 5 and y=3 --> 15>9 --> yes

I can't seem to find numbers that make the base question no if you combine 1) and 2)
But how do you really know that there does not exist a scenario where if you combine 1) and 2), that the base is not a yes?

Comment: What does (1) and (2) here mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if $x|y| > y^2 $ for all real $(x,y)$? (Clearly not, since $(0,0)$ violates the inequality.) Are (1), (2) supposed to be possible answers or further restrictions on $(x,y)$?

Comment: Hint:  $y^2 = |y|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is insufficient, because as you stated there are different scenarious where the answer could be yes or no that both fit constraint 1

2 is also insufficient, because we have no idea what x

If we put them both together, we know that x>y>0
because we know that y>0, we can multiply both sides of the inequality by y without having to worry about any sign switching.  This shows us that the inequality is essentially asking is x>y, which we know from 1 is true, so we know that x·|y| > y^2 and thus the answer is C

Answer (score 0):

According to condition 2 if y>0 so |y|=y>0 .Now dividing the inequation by y(as it is positive).so x>y.CONCLUSION:- considering (2) to be true (1) was proved.hence the answer should be B option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you combine the two statements, the base answer is always yes, so the answer is C). The reasoning is that if y>0 and x>y, then x is also positive. A product of two positive numbers is always greater than the square of the lesser of the two numbers.